# Manually using multiple types is faster than polymorphism?

Tags: c++

I need to make a list of objects to render... And now I started to wonder, disregarding style or personal preference and only considering performance, what alternative is faster?

Multiple types/switch statement:

```
void Object::Render()
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case BUTTON:
            RenderButton(this);
            break;
        case NOT_BUTTON:
            RenderNotButton(this);
            break;
        case WIDGET_ABC:
            RenderWidgetAbc(this);
            break;
    }
}
```

Or polymorphism:

```
virtual void Object::Render();

class Button : public Object
{
     void Render();
}
```

EDIT 1: If it may help, I am mentioning this will run in a ARM v6 device

EDIT 2: Currently the project has zero objects on it (part of the project objective is experiment using C++ in a more functional programming way), this is why this is being considered.

Also, this will be the most frequently called part of the code, in case it is implemented as switch statement, no other method will be called as this one, thus it is really performance critical.

EDIT 3: This part of the code is actually to handle a list of vertexes and UVs to dump into the GPU, the GPU is faster than the CPU, and I want to throw vertexes and UVs the fastest as possible to it. The rendering is not CPU bound. Also it will have polygonal objects, not only simple OS-like GUI.

Comment: Why should you care which is *faster*? You are ignoring other factors, like the extensibility. The speed is really the least important problem IMHO, at least before you measure and confirm that part of the  code is a hotspot.

Comment: For rendering buttons in a user interface (how many of those can you possibly fit on a screen? 100?), any possible difference in performance is completely negligible.

Comment: @us2012 For rendering anything, the cost of a virtual function call is not measurable compared to the cost of the actual rendering.

Comment: @JamesKanze Depends. When you're processing and rendering thousands upon thousands of 3D objects (primitives), as in many (though not all) video games, a virtual function call per object may be measurable -- and more importantly, is indicative of more figurative paper cuts. Luckily, smart people have figured out ways to approach those problems *without* ugly `switch`, partially because a `switch` isn't actually faster, having many of the same problems.

Comment: @delnan can you point me more information on that? (this code IS for a game, and it might in the future handle all rendering, not only GUI)

Comment: @speeder http://altdevblogaday.com has some bright guys writing about optimization among many other interesting things. Data-oriented design is what I was referring to specifically (see http://gamesfromwithin.com/data-oriented-design for one rather accessible explanation), though it's a rather broad idea rather than specific guidelines.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this is a bad question that deserve 4 downvotes?

Comment: don't use that functional approach in C++, it's not helping, because the compiler will not tell you where you are missing a switch case. That feature alone may justify the use of sum types in functional languages, but not in C++.

Comment: @speeder 'Performance' questions are always a bit of a problem on stackoverflow (especially with the C/C++ tags), and people seem to downvote those heavily if they (a) don't agree that your use case needs the optimization, (b) you are considering an optimization that they deem inferior to the 'standard way of doing things', or (c) think that the answer is obvious and you shouldn't have to ask. That *is* a little unfortunate and I would agree that this question does not deserve -4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran the following code to compare the two.  As I expected the virtual functions were slightly faster (I will explain why below).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

class Object
{
    public:
        enum Type
        {
            BUTTON,
            NOT_BUTTON,
            WIDGET_ABC
        };

        Object(Type type);

        virtual void renderVirtual() = 0;
        void renderSwitch();

        int counter;

    private:
        void renderButton();
        void renderNotButton();
        void renderWidgetAbc();

        Type type;
};

class Button : public Object
{
    public:
        Button();

        virtual void renderVirtual();
};

class NotButton : public Object
{
    public:
        NotButton();

        virtual void renderVirtual();
};

class WidgetAbc : public Object
{
    public:
        WidgetAbc();

        virtual void renderVirtual();
};

Object::Object(Type type)
    :type(type),
     counter(0)
{

}

void Object::renderSwitch()
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case BUTTON:
            renderButton();
            break;
        case NOT_BUTTON:
            renderNotButton();
            break;
        case WIDGET_ABC:
            renderWidgetAbc();
            break;
    }
}

void Object::renderButton()
{
    counter += 1;
}

void Object::renderNotButton()
{
    counter += 2;
}

void Object::renderWidgetAbc()
{
    counter += 3;
}

Button::Button()
    :Object(BUTTON)
{

}

void Button::renderVirtual()
{
    counter += 1;
}

NotButton::NotButton()
    :Object(NOT_BUTTON)
{

}

void NotButton::renderVirtual()
{
    counter += 2;
}

WidgetAbc::WidgetAbc()
    :Object(WIDGET_ABC)
{

}

void WidgetAbc::renderVirtual()
{
    counter += 3;
}

static struct timeval start, end;
static long mtime, seconds, useconds;

static void startTime()
{
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
}

static void printTimeDiff()
{
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    seconds  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
    useconds = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
    mtime = ((seconds) * 1000 + useconds/1000.0) + 0.5;
    printf("Elapsed time: %ld milliseconds\n", mtime);
}

int main()
{
    const int size = 10000000;
    Object *button = new Button();
    Object *notButton = new NotButton();
    Object *widgetAbc = new WidgetAbc();

    startTime();

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        button->renderVirtual();
        notButton->renderVirtual();
        widgetAbc->renderVirtual();
    }

    printf("Virtual Function:\n");
    printTimeDiff();
    printf("button counter = %d\n", button->counter);
    printf("notButton counter = %d\n", notButton->counter);
    printf("widgetAbc counter = %d\n", widgetAbc->counter);

    startTime();

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        button->renderSwitch();
        notButton->renderSwitch();
        widgetAbc->renderSwitch();
    }

    printf("Switch Function:\n");
    printTimeDiff();
    printf("button counter = %d\n", button->counter);
    printf("notButton counter = %d\n", notButton->counter);
    printf("widgetAbc counter = %d\n", widgetAbc->counter);

    return 0;
}
```

When I built using "g++ main.cpp" I got the following results

```
Virtual Function
Elapsed time 132 milliseconds
button counter = 10000000
notButton counter = 20000000
widgetAbc counter = 30000000
Switch Function
Elapsed time 206 milliseconds
button counter = 20000000
notButton counter = 40000000
widgetAbc counter = 60000000
```

I then build with -02 added (for optimization) and had the following results

```
Virtual Function
Elapsed time 58 milliseconds
button counter = 10000000
notButton counter = 20000000
widgetAbc counter = 30000000
Switch Function
Elapsed time 76 milliseconds
button counter = 20000000
notButton counter = 40000000
widgetAbc counter = 60000000
```

In both cases the virtual function was faster.

Although virtual functions are slower than non-virtual functions, the overhead is minimal.  A virtual function is most likely a function pointer (although a compiler could do it differently).  Therefore, when you call a virtual function, the only extra overhead is a pointer dereference.  Here is an example of what the compiler could be doing for a virtual call.  The compiler could do it a bit more elegantly but you can get the idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Object
{
    public:
        // function pointer acting as virtual function call
        void (*funcPtr) (void *this_ptr);
};

class Button : public Object
{
    public:
        Button();
        static void virtualFunc(void *this_ptr);

        int counter;
};

Button::Button()
    :counter(0)
{
    // set object function pointer to our "virtual function"
    funcPtr = &Button::virtualFunc;
}

void Button::virtualFunc(void *this_ptr)
{
    Button *button_ptr = reinterpret_cast<Button*>(this_ptr);
    button_ptr->counter++;
}

int main()
{
    Object *button = new Button();

    // virtual call using a function pointer
    button->funcPtr(button);

    printf("button counter = %d\n", static_cast<Button*>(button)->counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: which compiler, which platform, etc?

Comment: This was run on linux with x86 processor using g++ for the compiler.  I would expect virtual functions to be faster than a switch statement on nearly all platforms.

Comment: With clang 3.4 and GCC 4.9, I get the switch as being twice as fast as the virtual version (when optimizations are `-O2` or above for clang, and `-O3` and above for GCC). In my experience, the compiler can do better optimization with the switch. Yeah, it's a maintenance nightmare, but in some (performance critical) cases is justified to use the switch.

Answer (score 2):

I think performance difference will be small enough so that it can be ignored. However maintainability, testability and design will suffer a lot so I would not use the first version.

My experience shows that each time I try to outsmart the compiler using such small optimization I end up with having the host being actually smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Your first code is a maintenance and design nightmare. Think about the situation when you need to add new types!
As for the performance. Only profiling can give you a definite answer for your respective platform and environment.

Answer (score 0):

The version with the switch should be faster, since the polymorphism requires the object to be moved to cache, but this is really a micro-optimization.

I would go with polymorphism, because the code can be much better designed.

Comment: A lot depends on how the compiler implements this, but at least on some machines, calling a virtual function is faster than a switch.  (On others, probably not.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I agree, but it would still be a micro-optimization.

Comment: Clearly, chosing one solution over the other on a purported basis of difference of speed would be silly.  Especially as in each case, he's calling a function which will have to do significant work.  The total time spent in dispatching, regardless of the solution, is several magnitudes less than the time he'll spend in rendering.

Comment: Your phrasing is confusing. Or perhaps representative of your own confusion. Yes, touching any part of memory requires fetching the cache line it's on, but that's really for any part, so getting `type` will also bring something into cache. Polymorphism has *some* cost, but without much more detail I couldn't say which one is probably faster (a `switch` also incurs a branch).

Comment: @delnan You can't say which is faster without knowing more about the architecture.  On many architectures (Sparc, Intel), I would expect a virtual function call to be _slightly_ faster, but on others (HP's PA), any indirect jump will be very expensive.  (Note too that it depends on the number of cases: a switch will either use a jump table, with an indirect jump, or it will be O(lg n) for n cases.)

Comment: @delnan And finally: if the functions are trivial, the compiler is more likely to be able to inline them in the switch (although I've heard of compilers which can do it in the case of virtual functions as well, basically by doing global analysis and converting it into the switch).  But renders are _not_ normally trivial functions; they will generally do a fair amount of work.

Comment: @JamesKanze Did I say one is faster?

Comment: @JamesKanze I'd like to see the compiler that replaces virtual calls with switches. I know of devirtualization, which is local. But to replace the virtual call with a `switch` entirely, you'd have to see *all* classes, which is at odds with both separate compilation (and the LTO approaches I've seen work on such a low level that they don't even know what a vtable is) and with dynamic linking. As for triviality: If by "renderer" you mean "shapes -> pixels", then you may be right; but most graphics engines leave that to OpenGL/DX and instead do a number of other steps as "rendering".

Comment: @delnan In optimizing builds, most modern compilers only output something like byte code during the compile phase, and do the actual compilation when linking, using input from the profiler to determine when to inline.  Replacing virtual function calls with a switch is tricky, because there might be classes which are loaded from a DLL, and which aren't present in the profiling, but all that really means is that you need a default in the switch.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by faster?

Using polymorphism is faster just because

- it encapsulated behavior better
- maintainability is surely better (so it's faster for you, which is important)
- it allows more complex design in a simple way

From the mere point of view of performance the implementation of polymorphism is done through a lookup table and what is required is a double indirect reference to obtain the address of the dynamic called method. **This means that the time for polymorphism is constant**, even if it's not trivial because the method could be not loaded into cache.

Having a switch to call the appropriate method is just forgetting about OOP. It makes no sense to do it. It could be faster by some CPU cycles just because of cache hits/misses but it is not worth doing it almost never.